What is the Distance Range Between Camera and Objects in LINE-MOD Dataset Pose Annotations?
I'm currently working on implementing the LINE-MOD (Local INdependent MOdels) algorithm for real-time detection of texture-less 3D objects in cluttered environments. I came across the original LINE-MOD paper, which mentions the use of multimodal templates combining color images and dense depth maps.
However, I do not have access to my computer at the moment and cannot review the dataset or paper directly. I need to make a preliminary assessment regarding the spatial configuration between the camera and the objects to proceed with my project.
